How to allow generics to support string and number inputs with TypeScript
I am trying to create a component which I can use elsewhere by providing inputValue as a string or a number and the onValueChange will infer the same type automatically.
interface IPrimaryInput<T> {
  autofocus?: boolean;
  keyboardType?: "number-pad" | "default";
  placeholder: string;
  inputValue: T;
  onValueChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>;
}

function PrimaryInput<T extends string | number>({
  autofocus = true,
  keyboardType = "default",
  placeholder = "",
  inputValue,
  onValueChange,
}: IPrimaryInput<T>) {
  return (
    <TextInput
      autoFocus={autofocus}
      keyboardType={keyboardType}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      value={inputValue.toString() || ""}
      style={styles.inputPayment}
      onChangeText={(value) => {
        const updatedValue =
          typeof inputValue === "number" ? (Number(value) as T) : (value as T);
        onValueChange(updatedValue);
      }}
    />
  );
}

Here is how I use it
  <PrimaryInput
     placeholder={RecordPaymentPage.rupeeSymbol}
     keyboardType="number-pad"
     inputValue={paidAmount}
     onValueChange={setPaidAmount}
  />

Right now the inputValue is number but I wanted to use it for strings as well. the problem is typescript knows T is always a string|number and complains when I pass in a number Here is the error
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | number>>'.
  Type 'SetStateAction<string | number>' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<number>'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<number>'.ts(2322)
PrimaryInput.tsx(20, 3): 
The expected type comes from property 'onValueChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPrimaryInput<string | number>'

I've tried providing default value as string, tried to explicitly set the type (I could not do it of another error).
Can someone please guide me here?
